# Accessing Popup content from resources (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, resources, popup

In WPF, I need to access the "myControl" from code-behind when it is defined in the Resources section like below

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
    <ListView.Resources>
         <Popup x:Key="myPopup" >
             <Border>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                      <my:SomeControl Name="myControl" />
                 </StackPanel>
             </Border>
         </Popup>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

I am able to find the Popup resource with

```
Dim p As Popup = myListView.TryFindResource("myPopup")
```

...but how to continue to access what's inside the Popup, i.e. myControl in this case?

Comment: hi. adding a .net or c# tag to the footer of the question might help you to reach a bigger audience and get more answers for your question.

Comment: Once you have identified the popup, try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Popup's` are `not part of visual tree` so instead you should `traverse logical tree`. You can get to control like this -

```
var someControl = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(p, "myControl");
```